# EntityManagerFactory is closed

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I'm trying to autowire dependencies on a class that is not managed by Spring.
To do that I use the following

```
try (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:applicationContext.xml")) {
    AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    factory.autowireBean(this);
    factory.initializeBean(this, "logJaxSoapMessageHandler");

    context.refresh();
}
```

This instance has a dependency on a service, which has a dependency on a repository (managed by Spring data JPA).

Problem is : when I try to perform a `findOne` operation, I get this Exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:388)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:357)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor166.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:541)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.getCriteriaBuilder(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor166.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:203)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.getCriteriaBuilder(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:523)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findOne(SimpleJpaRepository.java:373)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:414)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:399)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:371)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
```

The `entityManagerFactory` seems to be already closed (or maybe never opened?) when I try to use it.

Do you have a clue on how to get this `EntityManagerFactory` open when I manually autowire the class?

Comment: Did you try @Transaction

Comment: Yes, my service is annotated @Transactional

Comment: Please tell me that you aren't using this in production code??? Code like this is quite dangerous and should be avoided. You are basically recreating the whole application, leading to strange to debug transactional, memory and performance exceptions. You should locate the already loaded `ApplicationContext` and reuse that, never create a new instance of the `ApplicationContext` because, as stated, that will recreate your whole application again.

Comment: I thought I was outside the context with no access to the current ApplicationContext but you were right; locating the current ApplicationContext even made the entityManagerFactory work properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum), I was creating a new `ApplicationContext` instead of getting the existing one.

I updated my code to look like this

```
ApplicationContextProvider appContextProvider = new ApplicationContextProvider();
ApplicationContext applicationContext = appContextProvider.getApplicationContext();

AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
factory.autowireBean(this);
factory.initializeBean(this, "logJaxSoapMessageHandler");
```

Where `ApplicationContextProvider` looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac)
        throws BeansException {
        context = ac;
    }
}
```

This works fine, as I get the previously initialized `EntityManagerFactory`.