# EntityManagerFactory is closed after application restarted with spring-boot-devtools

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I was looking into many Q&A in StackOverflow, none of them solved my issue or not matching my case. For example the following questions.

- [EntityManagerFactory is closed when page is reloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44874114/entitymanagerfactory-is-closed-when-page-is-reloaded)
- [EntityManagerFactory is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065877/entitymanagerfactory-is-closed-hibernate)
- [EntityManagerFactory is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445802/entitymanagerfactory-is-closed)

What my issue is, 
I am working on SpringBoot v2.2.5.RELEASE and MariaDB. I have added the spring-boot-devtools in my pom as below.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

My DataSource configuration in application.properties as below

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/db_name_here?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

I am running the application with following command via command line

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

as expected whenever any files change in the classpath, applications using this spring-boot-devtools cause the application to restart. Once after the application is restarted, if I am trying to relogin to the application, I am getting the below error.

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException
: EntityManagerFactory is closed
// truncated
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(SessionFactoryImpl.java:507) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
```

Only after stopping the process with CTRL+C and re-run the command, the application is working without entity manager issue. Please advice.

Comment: I had some operation in the application close event which caused the issue. Re arranging the order of the execution solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this exception when `EnableJpaRepositories` attribute was missing in the main application class from Spring Boot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class FooApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FooApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the stacktrace. It will probably give a service method. This service method must have a @Transactional annotation.